# Как сделать красивый текст?

Tags: photoshop, дизайн

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как оформить текст в таком же стиле как в лого этого сайта - http://www.vibethemes.com/ ? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Свой лого они рисовали, скорее всего, в векторном редакторе, а не в шопе. Можно сделать похоже:

1. понадобятся два "пути" (paths): внешний, то, что белое; и голубые буквы поуже;
2. из внешнего с помощью `3D - Repousse` можно сделать этот объём с белым "лицом" и градиентными боками;
3. выше - "узкий" путь: тонкая обводка (Stroke) и градиент (Gradient overlay) заполнения для букв.

Что, собственно, вы пытались сделать, и что не получилось?

Answer (score 2):

Вариант номер раз - выбираете понравившийся [шрифт аля "граффити"](http://ru.fontriver.com/script/graffiti/) и пишете им. Вариант второй - создаёте свой шрифт, который и будете использовать. Вариант третий - рисуете буквы ручками: или на бумаге, а потом сканируете, или сразу в какой-нибудь хорошо вам знакомой программе.